# How can I add a body class to a page through Layout Update XML - Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, html, layout-update

I'm trying to **add a unique body class to a category page** through the Layout Update XML.

Comment: The category page already has a body class generated from the category url path. [For example](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men.html) the category `Men/Tops Men` has the body class `categorypath-men-tops-men`

Answer (score 1):

You can use attributes for that:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="body-class" />
</body>
```